# Line breaks in markdown

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, editing, markdown

I have been seeing new users who copy/paste code or information into posts not add extra newlines(or even type without extra newlines) and make posts hard to read, wasting the time of a moderator or editor. Can this behavior be changed to make single linebreaks act as lienbreaks? Or is by design?

Comment: I see far too many users blindly copy-pasting from a forum, termian output, etc, and getting one big mess that will waste about 10 minutes of an editor. in alleviating the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is by-design - the [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) specifies a blank line between paragraphs.

*Code* should be indicated as such - [indented four spaces](https://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). There's a button on the toolbar and a shortcut key to accomplish this, and doing so also handles escaping special characters in cases where it otherwise can't be done automatically.